# Does Play Music download songs more than once if they are in different playlists?

Tags: storage, google-play-music, offline

I have several playlists which overlap in terms of the songs they contain. I have these downloaded on my phone. If a song is in two playlists, will it be stored twice on my phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

I went ahead and downloaded my master playlist that contains all my songs, then the other playlists. The latter all took zero time, indicating the songs were not downloaded twice

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I downloaded an album and added to a playlist to check this (and deleted everything from my library first) and after downloading the album alone I had 118mb of music. Then I downloaded the playlist and I had 236mb. . So yes yes it does